# GMP nearest integer

Tags: c, gmp

I'm using GMP in C and I'd like to round an `mpf` to an `mpz` by nearest integer. Is there a GMP function that will do this? My work-around has been:

```
void Mpf_round(mpz_t rop, const mpf_t op, int PRECISION){
    mpf_t dummy; mpf_init2(dummy,PRECISION);
    int compare_int;
    mpf_floor(dummy,op);
    mpf_sub(dummy,op,dummy);
    compare_int=mpf_cmp_d(dummy,0.5);
    mpf_floor(dummy,op);
    if(compare_int>0){
        mpf_add_ui(dummy,dummy,1);
        mpz_set_f(rop,dummy);
    }
    else
        mpz_set_f(rop,dummy);

    mpf_clear(dummy);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? I'm looking for something fast, since I'm calling this operation a lot.

Comment: I would recommend moving to MPFR (used to be part of GMP), where mpfr_get_z has a rounding parameter. mpf_t is kept in GMP for old code, but new code should use MPFR.